# Algorithm that can check for errors in a array of numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, redundancy

I have been given a task of writing a simple algorithm that checks the data inside an array, if the data has been altered then to show an error message.

I thought about counting the number of items inside the array, however this seems to be very simple and prone to ignore errors.

For example:

array = [1,2,3,4,5]

check length of array (5 items). Return true.

However I can see that if the values have been modified then I would still have 5 items like array array = [1,1,1,1,1] so the length would return true, but the values are not the same.

Anyone has any advice for different ways that I could check for data changes?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is that : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code

You need to define either the maximal additional data you can add, or the maximum number of errors you want to correct (ie : how many bits can be changed) or to detect. For example if you only want to detect at max one bit change, adding a bit with the bit parity of all numbers is enough (you are sure you will know if there is a change, but you wont know which bit has been changed)